# material icons cdn is not working in next.js

Tags: css, next.js, cdn, head, google-material-icons

I added cdn to next.js head section but it does not work.

```
import Head from "next/head";

<Head>
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    rel="stylesheet"
  ></link>
</Head>;
```

I tried to render this simple icon but it does not show any icon. it just simply shows string "add"

```
  <i className="material-icons">add</i>
```

Comment: Can you show the full code in the file you're adding `next/head`?

Comment: Also, which page is this on? If this is in the `_document.js` file, you need to `import { Head } from 'next/document'`

Comment: @Nick  this is not document.js. it is in baseLayou page I use in every page. fullcode of Head is just bunch of meta tags or open graph for seo purposes

Comment: any solution you got so far?

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same problem and the following worked for me:

Add the Google Material Icon CSS to the globals.css file instead of the xxxx.module.css. After I did this, icon name worked

Comment: how do you do this?

Comment: When you select an icon on Google Material Symbols, copy the style class under the Variable Icon Font section on the right (e.g. <style>
.material-symbols-outlined {
  font-variation-settings:
  'FILL' 0,
  'wght' 400,
  'GRAD' 0,
  'opsz' 48
}
</style>) and paste the class into your globals.css file (minus the <style> tags)

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I found is to use Code point instead of the icon name:

```
<Head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" 
rel="stylesheet" />
</Head>
<span className="material-icons">&#xe145;</span>
```

Comment: tried the solution you provided but its not working

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by disabling font optimization: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/font-optimization

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```css
// global.scss
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,1,0';
```